# .htaccess www to non www

Tags: .htaccess

I know there are lots of stack overflow posts about this. I have this in my /var/www/ directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It should rewrite all www.domain.com requests to http://domain.com. I have mod_rewrite enabled, and in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default, I have enabled htaccess:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

All www requests lead to a page not found error. I get a generic verizon search. What the hell am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
Here's the entire file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**rewrite log file**

```
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850f3b0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850f3b0/initial] (1) pass through /
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850f3b0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/ -> 
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850f3b0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri ''
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850f3b0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850f3b0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8506390/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8506390/subreq] (1) pass through /index.html
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8506390/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/index.html
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850d3a8/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.cgi
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850d3a8/subreq] (1) pass through /index.cgi
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850d3a8/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/index.cgi
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8506390/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.pl
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8506390/subreq] (1) pass through /index.pl
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8506390/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/index.pl
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850d3a8/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.php
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850d3a8/subreq] (1) pass through /index.php
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b850d3a8/subreq] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/index.php
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /css/style.css
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (1) pass through /css/style.css
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/css/style.css -> css/style.css
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'css/style.css'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/css/style.css
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8554138/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /js/scripts.js
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8554138/initial] (1) pass through /js/scripts.js
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8554138/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/js/scripts.js -> js/scripts.js
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8554138/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'js/scripts.js'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8554138/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8554138/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/js/scripts.js
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/HeaderBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (1) pass through /images/HeaderBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/images/HeaderBkg.gif -> images/HeaderBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/HeaderBkg.gif'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/images/HeaderBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/logo.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (1) pass through /images/logo.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/images/logo.png -> images/logo.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/logo.png'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/images/logo.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/SearchHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (1) pass through /images/SearchHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/images/SearchHeadingIco.gif -> images/SearchHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/SearchHeadingIco.gif'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85718b0/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/images/SearchHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b854f600/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/SearchKeywordBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b854f600/initial] (1) pass through /images/SearchKeywordBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b854f600/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/images/SearchKeywordBkg.gif -> images/SearchKeywordBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b854f600/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/SearchKeywordBkg.gif'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b854f600/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b854f600/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/images/SearchKeywordBkg.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/CategoriesHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (1) pass through /images/CategoriesHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/images/CategoriesHeadingIco.gif -> images/CategoriesHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/CategoriesHeadingIco.gif'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b8504388/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/images/CategoriesHeadingIco.gif
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85113b8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /images/SRightIco.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85113b8/initial] (1) pass through /images/SRightIco.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85113b8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/images/SRightIco.png -> images/SRightIco.png
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85113b8/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'images/SRightIco.png'
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85113b8/initial] (4) [perdir /var/www/] RewriteCond: input='domain.com' pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched
173.68.188.109 - - [10/Feb/2012:14:58:24 +0000] [domain.com/sid#b8370ad8][rid#b85113b8/initial] (1) [perdir /var/www/] pass through /var/www/images/SRightIco.png
```

Comment: Do you have the correct `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` in the `VirtualHost`? `ServerName example.com` `ServerAlias www.example.com`, if you're using name-based vhosts?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'm very new to server administration. I've posted what my entire /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file looks like above

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using name-based virtual hosting.  Look for the line `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your config files, but I expect you won't find it (or commented out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache was fine. I had to adjust the cname record for the DNS.

For anyone else having this problem, I changed my CNAME value to domain.com. It was www.domain.com. That was cause of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a `servername` & `serveralias` in your virtualhost.

[servername <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername)
[serveralias <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername)

Add them in you virtual host section.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com 
.
.
.
</virtualhost>
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLog "/path/to/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

Put the above 3 lines in your `virtualhost`. restart the httpd. and access `www.domain.com` *once* and paste the log here.

Comment: I added those two lines to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default and restarted apache. still not working :( I'm running Ubuntu if that matters at all.

Comment: I'm not getting errors. www.mydomain.com just leads to a verzion page not found. A general search page. I know .htaccess is working, because if i put junk characters in the file, I do get an internal server error

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I've posted my log file above. Nothing at all is written to the log when trying to access the site using www. What's above is what's written without the www. Oddly, it seems the page is being requested several times very quickly.

Comment: @MattKaye I can see: `pattern='^www\.(.+)$' [NC] => not-matched` access `www.domain.com` and paste the log.